# C++/opengl application running smoother with debugger attached

Tags: c++, opengl

Have you experienced a situation, where C++ opengl application is running faster and smoother when executed from visual studio? When executed normally, without debugger, I get lower framerate, 50 instead of 80, and a strange lagging, where fps is diving to about 25 frames/sec every 20-30th frame. Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit**:
Also we are using quite many display lists (created with glNewList). And increasing the number of display lists seem to increase lagging.

**Edit**:
The problem seems to be caused by page faults. Adjusting process working set with SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx() doesn't help.

**Edit**:
With some large models the problem is easy to spot with procexp-utility's GPU-memory usage. Memory usage is very unstable when there are many glCallList-calls per frame. No new geometry is added, no textures loaded, but gpu-memory-allocation fluctuates +-20 Mbytes. After a while it becomes even worse, and may allocate something like 150Mb in one go.

Comment: Are you running full screen, vs not in full screen in the debugger?  That would point to V-sync being enabled.

Comment: Not fullscreen, but maximized. V-sync should be disabled in both cases. Sometimes I get fps-rates over 100, and still lagging.

Comment: you should use something like Process Explorer to see which DLLs get loaded in both cases and if the same DLL gets loaded from differenc paths

Comment: All dll files seem to match. There's a couple of dlls that are only present when executing from Visual Studio: audiodev.dll, WMVCORE.DLL, wpdshext.dll, GdiPlus.dll, WMASF.DLL. In theory these shouldn't affect the smoothness of opengl rendering.

Comment: When you run the program outside of VS, do you use the debug version or the release one?

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/displaylist.htm this faq suggests that memory thrashing is often times a performance constraint with display lists. Maybe your application inherits some memory priority or cache size from the parent process. Try to start your application as administrator or from the visual studio command line to see if there's any difference. Also try to look at memory parameters such as page-faults in the task-manager and see if there's any significant difference.

Comment: +1. I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @PeterT: yes, when executing in VS there's practically no page faults, while normally there's about 80 page faults per second. Hmm, any idea how to optimize memory allocation so to minimize page faults?

Comment: @AareP Try setting the working set size with `SetProcessWorkingSetSize ()` to a big value. Don't forget to check the return value for errors, as this function is likely to fail if you are not careful.

Comment: @rodrigo: will try, but it seems those values are the same in both cases. I added print out of GetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx() values and there is no difference.

Comment: And what happens if you run the program outside of VS and then _attach_ the debugger to the running process?

Comment: You have not provided source code. Without source code you could as well ask fortune-teller.

Comment: You probably implemented window repainting inefficiently - using timer or something similar, or you calculate fps improperly. Or use sleep between frames and calculate delay incorrectly. A "clear window" opengl app that simply clears window and swaps buffers should give 600..1200 fps on virtually any computer. If you aren't getting that many frames, you have a programming problem somewhere and update/repaint window inefficiently (repainting should be done during "idle processing" or straight within message loop after PeekMessage). Anyway, there's not enough info to figure out the problem.

Comment: "And what happens if you run the program outside of VS and then attach the debugger to the running process?" - same result as executing without debugger, fps is lagging.

Comment: "You probably implemented window repainting inefficiently" - I timed the execution. Unnecessary time is spent glCallLists, when drawing lots of display lists. So, the problem is in those page faults, which are happening only in normal execution.

Comment: Can you check (with ProcessExplorer) whether the current directory and the command line are exactly the same in both cases? Also, you did check that most DLL are common in both cases, but did you check that they both load the exact same version of the DLLs? Note that some DLLs have a lot of versions with the same name but different directory (look at the "Path" column, not name, in ProcessExplorer).

Comment: AareP: timing rendering calls is not a good idea, because rendering can be performed asynchronously and be actually finished after the call has been completed. You can reliably measure time between buffer swaps, but that's it - all other timing data is not very trustworthy. And again - if you want help, post source code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I believe nobody can answer your question, there are endless possibilities, that's unusual and impossible to track-down the issue without Source code.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that what you are seeing is the debugger locking some pages so they couldn't be swapped to be immediately accessible to the debugger. This brings some caveats for OS at the time of process switching and is, in general, not reccommended.

You will probably not like to hear me saying this, but there is no good way to fix this, even if you do.

Use VBOs, or at least vertex arrays, those can be expected to be optimized much better in the driver (let's face it - display lists are getting obsolete). Display lists can be easily wrapped to generate vertex buffers so only a little of the old code needs to be modified. Also, you can use "bindless graphics" which was designed to avoid page faults in the driver (GL_EXT_direct_state_access).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an nVidia graphics card by any chance? nVidia OpenGL appears to use a different implementation when attached to the debugger. For me, the non-debugger version is leaking memory at up to 1 MB/sec in certain situations where I draw to the front buffer and don't call glClear each frame. The debugger version is absolutely fine.

I have no idea why it needs to allocate and (sometimes) deallocate so much memory for a scene that's not changing.

And I'm not using display lists.

Comment: Thank you! I confirm nVidia OpenGL drivers have a substantial performance difference (x100) between Release and Debug versions under certain conditions. I had an OpenGL project that used skinned animations and it would run at .4FPS on two different nVidia based Windows machines. However the project would run at about 30FPS on AMD machines or on my Macbook's nVidia hardware. However on the Windows/nVidia machines if I ran the project with Unity's Profiler Window open it would speed up from .4FPS to 30FPS, and if I ran the standalone through an OpenGL debug tool it would also run at 30FPS.

Comment: @RiazRizvi
I'm currently encountering similar issues and was wondering which OpenGL debug tool you were using?

Comment: It was a while ago, but I think it was this free one https://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/gDEBugger/. My conclusion was that Window's OpenGL DLLs built for debug, perform better than the release version, for skinned animations, since running the project through the debug tool causes the debug versions of the OpenGL drivers to load. Again though this was two years ago - not sure if it's still the case.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the thread or process priority.  Visual Studio might launch your process with a slightly higher priority to make sure the debugger is responsive.  Try using [SetPriorityClass()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your app's code:

```
SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);
```

The 'above normal' class just nudges it ahead of everything else with the 'normal' class.  As the documentation says, don't slap on a super high priority or you can screw up the system's scheduler.

In an app running at 60 fps you only get 16ms to draw a frame (less at 80 fps!) - if it takes longer you drop the frame which can cause a small dip in framerate.  If your app has the same priority as other apps, it's relatively likely another app could temporarily steal the CPU for some task and you drop a few frames or at least miss your 16 ms window for the current frame.  The idea is boosting the priority slightly means Windows comes back to your app more often so it doesn't drop as many frames.

Comment: Seens reasonable, but what's the relation of your answer with the performance difference between debug/release versions?

Comment: Didn't help. Fps rate is still "unstable" when executing separately from visual studio. Btw I'm always using Release version, but executing either from visual studio or normally.

Comment: Also changing SetProcessPriorityBoost doesn't help.