# Release Build is faster, when started from Visual Studio than started "normally"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have a Qt application which has the purpose to visualize workpieces. Therefore we are using Qt's OpenGL interface `QGLWidget`. In this application, we sometimes have to load and visualize a lot of data (up to 4GB of double points in 3D). The application then gets slow, but this does not matter, because performance is not the real problem here. Rendering one frame usually takes around 100 ms.

The problem we are approaching is the following:
After the moment, when the program created the heavy data and we have loaded it, we normally need a lot of RAM. The allocation of the memory is a lot of faster, when the application is started from Visual Studio, than when started "normally".

In the task-manager I can see, that the speed of the increasing needed memory is very different. While the one application can allocate like 1GB of memory in a second, the other one can only allocate like 50MB per second.

My question is, what is the difference, when an application is started from Visual Studio? Both times, we are using the "defaullt" Release build from VS. What can trigger such kind of problems and how can I determine the source of these problems?

Additional information: This application is based on Qt5. There is an 10 year old version of this application, programmed with Qt3 and Qt4. We don't have the sources of this application anymore. When used Qt3/4, we don't approach these problems. It seems like the behaviour of the old app is the same, as when the Qt5 application is started with VS.
We are using Visual Studio 2015 and Qt5.9.1

I traced both times CPU usage and memory usage:

With Visual Studio:
[image]

Without Visual Studio:
[image]

You can see, that the increasing of the memory size of the first one is much faster, than the second one.

Comment: Make sure that the standalone application uses the same set of libraries as one that's started by VS. It might be that one of the versions use debug libraries, or it's a debug version.

Comment: Is it 'fast' or 'slow' if startet from VS, but without debugging (ctrl+F5) ?

Comment: @darune it is slow, when started without debugging

Comment: @vahancho used libraries are the same

Comment: @RoQuOTriX, it might be that Visual Studio sets some environment variables that isn't a case when you start the application normally.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Could you try launching the application, not from Visual Studio, but with debugging (using CDB)?

Comment: @BenjaminT I tried it with CDB. Both the Release and Debug version are showing the fast behaviour like when started with VS

Comment: @BenjaminT It is even fast, when I start the process and then attach to it with CDB

Comment: @RoQuOTriX To my knowledge Windows uses different memory allocators in Debug and Release builds: the debug version allocates slightly more memory. Could it be that when you run your program with a debugger attached, the same kind of thing happens? This could means less calls to the system memory allocator and therefore better performances. This could be something worth to take a look at.

Comment: @BenjaminT I think I found the problem, it is not the memory allocation itself. It is, that I create a lot of page faults, when the app is running without VS. Now I only have to find out, how to reduce them

Comment: @RoQuOTriX It might be worth checking if you do not access often data that is scatterred in memory. Keeping often-used data close together in memory improve the performances. For this reason it is better to use vectors than `QList`.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX what happends if you start without debugger - then, shortly after starting, attach the debugger to your process ? is it then fast or slow ?

Comment: @darune as i mentioned. When i start it without debugging, then attach CDB, it is fast, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the differences you are seeing is that when a debugger gets attached, the OS/debugger will lock some pages so that they are immediately available to the debugger. This is an exceptional condition because you attached a debugger and isn't recommended in generel. I believe there is no quick fix - perhaps only to use opengl in different ways.

See also this answer that probably had the same cause:

[C++/opengl application running smoother with debugger attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858128/c-opengl-application-running-smoother-with-debugger-attached)