# Write code, which does not cause many page faults

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I have a code for rendering an OpenGL scene. This code is causing many page faults, when started without visual studio. The code seen in `paintGL()` is only a fraction what happens there, but it takes the most time.

Example code:

```
void prepareData() {

       std::vector<int> m_indices; // vector of point indices, that should be connected
       std::vector<float> m_vertices; // vector of the 3d points

       /*
           fill the vectors
       */
}


void MyGLWidget::paintGL() {    

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i < m_indices.size(); i++)
    {
        // search end of strip
        if (m_indices[i] < 0)
        {
            // store end of strip
            endStrip = i;

            // we need at least three vertices for a triangle strip
            if (startStrip+2 < endStrip)
            {
                // draw strip
                for (unsigned int j=startStrip; j<endStrip; j++) {
                    idx = 3 * m_indices[j];
                    glVertex3dv(m_vertices[idx]));
                } 
            }

            // store start of next strip
            startStrip = i+1;
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

So here is the problem: when the data changes and gets calculated, the next call of `paintGL()` is very slow, because accessing the new values causes a lot of page faults.
When the data does not change, `paintGL()` is as fast as it should be.
Both data vectors can get be really big, normally we have sizes like 10 million indices and 15 million vertices.

My question is, how can I achieve to make the `paintGL` faster, when the values to display are freshly calculated?
When the application is started with Visual Studio (both Releae builds), there aren't that many page faults and it is faster than normal. How does Visual Studio achieve that and can I do this too, without visual studio monitoring my application.

The problem was already described here, but now I have found out the root cause for the problem: [Release Build is faster, when started from Visual Studio than started “normally”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164217/release-build-is-faster-when-started-from-visual-studio-than-started-normally?noredirect=1#comment97075918_55164217)

Additional information: [C++/opengl application running smoother with debugger attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858128/c-opengl-application-running-smoother-with-debugger-attached)

Comment: How do you measure the amount of "page faults"?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I look at the number with the process explorer and then see it rising heavily, when the rendering happens after prepareData(). I can see it, because rendering takes 10-100 seconds without Visusal Studio. When started with VS page fault number stays small and rendering takes like 150-200 ms (this is acceptable)

Comment: Any particular reason for using OpenGL 1.X? Using it to render millions of vertices is just horrible CPU drain.

Comment: @Quimby the application was first developed in 1998 and since then only some minor features or bugfixes were implemented. I don't really know OpenGL and the code base become a mess since then. My task is now, to fix this mess, so we can use the app in future, too. When I start using a new OpenGL version, I think I would have to write the complete code new. Furthermore, this code wasn't really a problem until the app development switched from XP to windows 7. The old version of this appcompiled for xp is as fast as it should be. I can't access the old code though

Comment: @RoQuOTriX That's valid reason. But the old version was never meant to handle this many calls, still no reason why it should not always take those 150ms, but I think you are at mercy of the graphics driver and how it handles its memory.

Comment: The GPU driver is handling RAM memory in a unoptimized way. Each time (or blocks of times) `glVertex3dv` is used it must ask the OS for more memory, which means "not contiguous" memory or "lot of relocations". While for small amounts this issue may not affect, for large data I'd try the `glMapBuffer` route. Even considering using modern OGL is worth if data (which for modern OGL is stored inside gfx car memory) doesn't change very frequently.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: `glBegin` / `glEnd` was already outdated in 1998. Client side vertex array support has been around since OpenGL-1.1, and Nvidia actually introduced GPU side vertex buffers with their GeForce2 series GPUs in 1998 as an OpenGL extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increased page fault load is just a secondary symptom of the really poor rendering loop. Modern GPUs operate on (large/-ish) buffers of vertex and index data. When using `glBegin`…`glEnd` intermediate mode, the driver is forced to create such buffers in situ. To speed things up there are a lot of heuristics, including the drivers also marking pages so that they get notified, if the contents of the pages changes, so that buffers are recreated only when needed.

Rewrite it to use indexed triangles in a vertex array, this is the mode GPUs and OpenGL drivers work best.

Even a client side vertex array will massively speed things up, since the driver can then coalesce the buffer copy. Of course the best thing would be, if you could just place `m_vertices` in a Vertex Buffer Object.

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// overloaded wrappers to deduce the
// GL type from the type of the index buffer vector
namespace gl_wrap {
    void DrawElements(
        GLenum mode, GLsizei count,
        std::vector<GLubyte> const &idx_buffer,
        size_t offset )
    {
        glDrawElements(mode, count, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, idx_buffer.data()+offset);
    }

    void DrawElements(
        GLenum mode, GLsizei count,
        std::vector<GLushort> const &idx_buffer,
        size_t offset )
    {
        glDrawElements(mode, count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, idx_buffer.data()+offset);
    }


    void DrawElements(
        GLenum mode, GLsizei count,
        std::vector<GLuint> const &idx_buffer,
        size_t offset )
    {
        glDrawElements(mode, count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, idx_buffer.data()+offset);
    }
}

void MyGLWidget::paintGL() {    

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    std::vector<std::pair<size_t,size_t>> strips;

    size_t i_prev = 0, i = 0;
    for( auto idx : m_indices ){
        ++i;
        if( idx < 0 ){
             strips.push_back(std::make_pair(i_prev, i-i_prev));
             i_prev = i;
        }
    }

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, m_vertices.data());
    for( auto const &s : strips ){
        gl_wrap::DrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, m_indices.data(), s.second, s.first);
    }

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with gl_wrap::DrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, s.second, s.first); 
Every method in the namepsace consists of 4 parameters. The call has only 3 parameters

Comment: So I implemented your suggestions and the normal rendering got faster, but not the first time after the data got calculated. The page faults for the first time stayed in my program. But I will use your code, because it is faster, thanks!